# Bootstrap modal return multiple values from

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to return multiple values as an object outside of bootstrap modal window on hide it.
My code is:

```
    modal.on('hide', function() {
        var o = new Object();
            o.formId = $(this).children('.modal-body').children('form').attr('id');
            o.schemaName = $(sn, modal).val();
        console.log(o)    // ->> this is works OK, obviously
    });
```

But I want something like:

```
    var ceva = modal.on('hide', function() {
        var o = new Object();
            o.formId = $(this).children('.modal-body').children('form').attr('id');
            o.schemaName = $(sn, modal).val();
        return o;
    });
    console.log(ceva);  // but this is returning all modal object instead o obj
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank's in advance! Leo.

Comment: You can't return value in an event handler which is an asynchronous process, `.on()` returns the collection, i.e the `modal` object. Create a function that accepts the object and call it `yourFunc(o)`.